# Does the magnitude of heat energy given or taken the same in any reference frame

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, energy, reference-frames, relative-motion

So the question consists of two parts-

1. The random motion of the particles is equivalent the amount of heat energy. The velocity of collective motion does not result in heat energy. For example take the case of wind. The particles are collectively moving with some velocity (wind velocity) but there isn't any heat energy associated with that motion ( otherwise the faster the wind, the hotter it would be). To understand this is simple. The wind velocity constitutes  the kinetic energy. And we can move onto a reference frame where the velocity of the collective motion of the particles is 0 but the velocity of the random motion still remains. **That makes me state that the amount of heat energy given or taken in any process should be the same in any inertial reference frame, because the velocity of random motion will always exist in any inertial frame whereas the velocity of collective motion can be eliminated by choosing suitable reference frames.**

Is my reasoning correct... and if so then will the magnitude of heat energy ( given or taken) remain the same even in an accelerated frame...
I think it should because the velocity of random motion will still be the same.

2)**If I stir and shake a bucket of warm water, it gets colder. But I am  actually increasing its velocity of random motion, so it should get hotter.** Why does it turn colder rather than turning hotter.

Comment: When you stir a bucket of water, it gets hotter.

Comment: @ChetMiller  is my reasoning in 1) correct.. Is  what I have deduced correct... 2) really, when I shake a bucket of hot water it gets colder quickly that compared to when I dont

Comment: Not if it is insulated.

Comment: @ChetMiller 1) are you saying that if the bucket is insulates then the water will get hotter on stirring and shaking. 2) and is my deduction in point 1 correct or faulty ( that amount of heat energy given or taken is equal in any frame)

Comment: Sure, if the bucket is insulated, the water will get hotter on stirring and shaking.  By stirring and shaking, you are doing viscous deformation work on the water, and, by the first law this "viscous heating" translates into an increase in internal energy.  It is just that the amount of work you are doing is usually small, so you would have to stir it for a long time before the heating would become pretty noticeable.  With regard to item 1, I am not able to follow your arguments.

Comment: @ChetMiller ok thanks I understand that. Regarding 1) I am trying to show that heat energy shouldn't be arising from the velocity of collective motion. Like you have a bucket of water at rest at some temperature. Now suppose that same bucket is moving at a high speed. This motion of the bucket ( and the water) should not increase the heat energy in the water. You should see the same temperature of water even if the bucket is moving. Because energy coming from this motion of the bucket goes into the kinetic energy and not the heat energy. To see that that even more clearly suppose you see a

Comment: @ChetMiller bucket of water at rest at some temperature. Now instead of allowing the bucket to move, suppose you start moving with some velocity wrt the bucket, the temperature of the water should not increase by this. That is the heat energy of the bucket should not increase when you start moving wrt it. The amount of heat energy ( temperature) should be the same in every frame. I am asking if you agree with this or not.....

Comment: Yes, I agree with this.  The internal energy of a substance is independent of the frame of reference of the observer.

Comment: @ChetMiller do you even agree if the frame of reference for one observer is accelerated wrt to the frame of the other observer. That is will the heat energy ( temperature) be the same in Frame A and Frame B, where Frame B is now accelerated wrt to Frame A  ( that is what I as was asking in 1))

Comment: When kinetic energy is transfer to kinetic energy it results in a net movement but when heat energy to heat energy is transfer its vibrational/rotational. the transfer of energy is different whn heat&momentum. These phonons then interact with the electrons to produce IRradiation thats basically continuous atleast 4 solids. Maybe it is the phonon electron interaction thats responsible for heat to heat transfer tht results in the molecule vibrational& rotational changes. I say this becz forwards isoften backwards where a object may fluresce with UV light and emit UVunder visble light in reverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the observer is accelerating, he will perceive a body force on the bucket in the opposite direction of the acceleration, and interpret the change in kinetic energy as associated with a corresponding change in potential energy.  So he would correctly conclude that there is no change in internal energy.

Comment: Ok yeah so in this case the potential energy will change... but not the internal energy..Thanks.. BTW are pseudo forces always conservative ( to interpret the work done by pseudo forces as potential energy like you have done)

Comment: I think that pseudo forces are always conservative.