# Is temperature a Lorentz scalar

Tags: special-relativity, temperature, inertial-frames, invariants

If I see a body at temperature $T$, will I see the same temperature in another frame under a Lorentz boost. And will the internal energy of a body also remain invariant under a Lorentz boost or not..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is temperature a Lorentz invariant in relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83488/)

Comment: @G.Smith, is this an open problem for *entropy* in different frames?

Comment: @G.Smith Ok I bit, I would say. Is Landsberg's result final or not. And I have a question for internal energy too which doesn't seem to be answered there. Is internal energy Lorentz invariant as Chet Miller is suggesting here or not https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595137/113699. Can you let me know if internal energy is a Lorentz invariant or not.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Ohh, I didn't know question was an open problem, I thought it would be trivial. But what about internal energy, is it Lorentz invariant or not..

Comment: This recent article may help you https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-17526-4

Comment: @nielsnielsen I don’t know. [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265922/lorentz-invariance-of-entropy) about entropy and Lorentz transformations didn’t get any answers.